# Websphere MQ client deploy to Jboss Fuse

Tags: java, jboss, ibm-mq

Error appear when MQConnectionFactory try to create connection. 
At the same time I'm able to send\receive message from standalone application.

jboss stack trace.

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: JMSCMQ0001, 2, MQCC_FAILED, 2195, MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:209)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'hostname(1450)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2195],3=hostname(1450),5=WMQThreadPool.enqueue]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2053)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1226)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:346)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.WMQThreadPool.enqueue(WMQThreadPool.java:109)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.setUpAsyncMode(RemoteConnection.java:1554)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.initSess(RemoteConnection.java:1348)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:727)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:400)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:299)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:164)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1598)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.CSIException: JMSCS0002
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.PIWorkQueueManager.enqueueItem(PIWorkQueueManager.java:67)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.enqueue(WorkQueueManager.java:225)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.enqueue(WorkQueueManager.java:194)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.WMQThreadPool.enqueue(WMQThreadPool.java:91)
```

*Query manager log:*

```
----- amqrmrsa.c : 898 --------------------------------------------------------
24.03.2015 17:09:06 - Process(21296.261) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(localserver-name) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(manager-name)

AMQ9209: Connection to host 'jboss-short-hostname (jboss-ip)' for channel
'channel-name' closed.

EXPLANATION:
An error occurred receiving data from 'jboss-short-hostname (jboss-ip)' over TCP/IP. 
The connection to the remote host has unexpectedly terminated. 

The channel name is 'channel-name'; in some cases it cannot be determined and so
is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Tell the systems administrator.
----- amqccita.c : 3843 -------------------------------------------------------
24.03.2015 17:09:06 - Process(21296.261) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(localserver-name) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(7.5.0.2) QMgr(manager-name)

AMQ9999: Channel 'channel-name' to host 'jboss-short-hostname (jboss-ip)' ended
abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 21296 for channel 'channel-name'
ended abnormally. The host name is 'jboss-short-hostname (jboss-ip)'; in some cases
the host name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage"
attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be
found in the System Administration Guide.
----- amqrmrsa.c : 898 --------------------------------------------------------
```

*About my test stand:*
Fuse Fabric  (7.2.0.redhat-024)
IBM WebSphere MQ  Version : 7.5.0.2
Java 1.7

Server WebSphere MQ and jboss installed on different servers.

I installed as features following jars:

```
com.ibm.mq.osgi.directip_7.5.0.2.jar
com.ibm.mq.osgi.java_7.5.0.2.jar
com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.commonservices.j2se_7.5.0.2.jar
com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.jms.prereq_7.5.0.2.jar
com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.jms_7.5.0.2.jar
com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.nls_7.5.0.2.jar
com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq.nls_7.5.0.2.jar
com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq.prereq_7.5.0.2.jar
com.ibm.msg.client.osgi.wmq_7.5.0.2.jar
```

My code snippet:

```
 MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();

            // Config
            cf.setHostName("hostname");
            cf.setPort("port");
            cf.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
            cf.setChannel("channel-name");
            cf.setQueueManager("manager-name");
            MQQueueConnection connectionDpc = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection("user", "pass");
```

Comment: 2195 is MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR. Do you have any FDCs?

Comment: I found *.fdc just in path "/var/mqm/errors", but its not relative(old errors).
Can I find it somewhere else?

Comment: That is the place FDCs are written, so you don't need to look elsewhere (assuming you've checked both client and server machines).

Comment: We have been forced to do own maven wrap for this jar. There are few troubles with cycles dependencies and compatibilities between equinox and felix(IBM build jar for equinox and Jboss use felix)

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the IBM MQ 7.5.0.6 (or later) OSGI bundles.  The 7.5.0.2 bundles are known to have this issue.